# Why are questions valued more than answers?

Tags: discussion, badges

Stack Overflow values questions more than answers. For example [11.8 million question badges have been awarded but only 4.2 million answer badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

You could say this is explained by voting behavior, but Stack Overflow sets the thresholds for badges and the badge stats show its easier to earn a question badge than an answer badge.

What is the reason for rewarding question authors more than answer givers?

I might add this is not a rhetorical question, is there a reason this makes the site more healthy?

Comment: Did you sum up over all possible question badges to get to the 11.8m? I don't think that gives a correct statement.

Comment: Yes, I added up all of the badges awarded under the question section. Let me know if you get a different number.

Comment: em no .. Nice Answer and Nice Question are equivalent

Comment: Why would you compare Nice Answer (vote based) with Popular Question (view based). If you want to compare then use Nice Answer (1m) vs. Nice Question (489k)

Comment: Just spotted that myself and removed from comment. The difference is almost entirely down to Popular Question badges (there is no answer equivalent)

Comment: This is my first post on Meta. If anyone wants to downvote it would be useful if you could post a comment why you think this is a bad question.

Comment: Voting on meta works different to the main side: Votes on meta can show agreement/disagreement and are not necessarily related to the quality of the question. Votes here will also not influence you reputation.

Comment: @stu in my case, I downvoted because the premise is ridiculous, no offense meant. A number of badge is not proof or evidence of opinion of anyone. There are far too much variables to make this assumption.

Comment: @BDL That's specifically only supposed to be for feature requests. This is not a feature request. From the "[what is meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)" page: *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.*

Answer (score 15):

Simply summing up all possible question/answer badges does not give a good estimate on how much something is valued.

1. There are more askers than answerers. There are also a lot of askers who only ask one question and never do anything else, while answerers usually have a large number of answers. Due to this, badges that are awarded just once per person skew the statistics towards the asker side.
2. View based badges are only awarded to the question side, not to the answer side. But I would argue that someone who reads the question will also read the answers. If you take away the view based badges (6.1m total), then there is no large difference between question and answer badges.
3. Then there are ~95k question badges that are either related to bounties or favoring question. Since bounties and favorites only exist on question level, they should also not be counted.

When only looking at vote based badges (Nice/Good/Great Question, Nice/Good/Great Answer), then the statistics show a clear favor towards answers. Question badges: 673k, Answer badges: 1.395m.

Comment: Along with view based there is also favoriting and bounty based badges for questions

Comment: In the last paragraph, I suppose you mean "the statistics show a clear favor towards the *answerers*".

Answer (score 10):

> Stack Overflow values questions more than answers.

No, it doesn't. An upvoted answer gets you 10 reputation; an upvoted question only 5. Reputation matters (way) more than badges; reputation gives privileges and badges don't (except for gold tag badges).

---

Sidenote: you should include the tag badges into your calculation. Questions do not count towards tag badges, only answers do.

Comment: It would be interesting to know what rate votes are made on questions/answers. A quick look at a few questions suggests about 50/50 to me, so yes, I agree reputation looks stacked toward answers.

Comment: Also, the only badges that give privileges (gold tag badges) are awarded for answers.

Answer (score 3):

Badges do not value primarily the user's reputation but should encourage activities that are positive to the community. Therefore the comparison answer and questions badges are not a reliable source for your conclusion that questions are more valued than answers.

The real value is expressed in your score (and in the "Tag Badges"). Concerning the scores: upvoted answers have more value (+10) than upvoted questions (+5). This contradicts your conclusion.

There are several reasons why there are more question badges than answer badges awarded:

1. There are slightly more question badges (18 vs. 17)
2. All answer badges need positive votes by the community. So they
   really represent quality criteria by the community.
3. Some question badges do not need a positive vote by the community.
   You have just to do the required action (whenever you reach the
   required reputation threshold) and you will get the badge.
   Alphabetically sorted: Altruist, Benefactor, Investor, Promotor,
   Scholar.
4. Some other question badges do not need many positive votes: e.g.
   Curios require asking 5 questions on 5 separate days with just a
   positive question record. Similar: Inquisitive, Socratic, Student.
5. You get the question badge "Tumbleweed" whenever the community is
   lacking interest in your question, e.g. it is a "bad" badge (zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week).

**To sum it up**: Question badges are easier to get than answer badges. But more important: A general comparison between question and answer badges says nothing about their value.